# The complement of the language L={a^n b^n | n !=100}

Tags: regular-language, formal-languages, context-free-language

I dont need a proof, since this is an objective exam question and allowed 2 mins only. The options are `regular` or `cfl` or `csl`. I dont understand how to tackle this.

If we I write it as

```
(a^n b^n | n<100) UNION (a^n b^n | n>100)
```

Now call first part L1 and second part L2 and then try to compliment using,

> De-morgons Law L'= L1' INTERSECTION L2'

I dont think thats the right way or a quick way considering the fact we need to spend 2-3 mins only. Any better approch to this?

Comment: Wouldn't the complement simply be {w ∈ Σ* | w != a^n b^n ∀ n != 100} (i.e. Σ*\L)?

Comment: Thanks @Njol but compliment is given by Sigma* - L which I think has more strings than what your language shows, I maybe wrong , but I usually convert language into what it "says". According to me compliment of the given language means that mean All strings that are not a^100 b^100. This looks right but still not sure.

Comment: A complement in general (i.e. in set theory) is the universe (which depends on the context, for languages it's Σ* I guess), minus the set. Thus if you have the definition of the set you can simply negate it to get the complement.

Comment: Yes but here how do I know what class of language I endup doing a compliment, surely it would be inside CSL but how to say its not in regular or cfl or csl, some discussion on a facebook group ended up in a conclusion that its cfl, but I dont understand it a single bit and doubt its correctness. I can share it here if I dont get voted down for pasting its link here.

Comment: L is a CFL as {a^n b^n ∀ n ∈ N} is a CFL. And since the complement of a CFL cannot be a CFL your only option left is CSL. BTW: You should rephrase the question if you want to know the class of the complement of L.

Comment: @Njol `since the complement of a CFL cannot be a CFL` is NOT CORRECT it may or may not be a CFL. I know its cfl (L), and i think question is asking about its compliment only, still I'll make it more clear

Comment: I'll better cease this discussion then because I can't come up with a (valid) simple proof for the class of L complement :S

Answer (score 2):

That is the right way to do, 
L = {a^n b^n | n<100} UNION {a^n b^n | n>100}

The first part is regular and second part is DCFL. 
Now, L' = COMP({a^n b^n | n<100}) INTERSECT COMP({a^n b^n | n>100})

regular complement is always regular and DCFL complement is always DCFL and hence CFL.

So, Regular intersect CFL gives CFL.